# Can't rename DLL file on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename, dll, fat32

I downloaded the [PicoScope SDK](https://www.picotech.com/downloads/_lightbox/pico-software-development-kit-64bit), and I am trying to rename one of the DLLs (according to their [programmer's guide p.5](https://www.picotech.com/download/manuals/PicoScope3000SeriesAApiMatlabInstrumentDriverGuide.pdf)). However, Windows 10 won't let me do this.

I'm trying to change the file name from `ps3000a.dll` to `PS3000a.dll`.

The file is located on a FAT32 USB drive.

Is there any reason why this doesn't work?

[image: GIF of the problem]

---

It doesn't seem to work via command line either. Git Bash:

```
MINGW64 /f/SDK/lib
$ ls | grep 3000a.dll
ps3000a.dll*

MINGW64 /f/SDK/lib
$ mv ps3000a.dll PS3000a.dll

MINGW64 /f/SDK/lib
$ ls | grep 3000a.dll
ps3000a.dll*
```

PowerShell:

```
PS F:\SDK\lib> dir | findstr 3000a.dll
-a----        7/11/2017   3:05 PM        2803016 ps3000a.dll
PS F:\SDK\lib> mv ps3000a.dll PS3000a.dll
PS F:\SDK\lib> dir | findstr 3000a.dll
-a----        7/11/2017   3:05 PM        2803016 ps3000a.dll
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your gif makes it look like you're only trying to change the "ps" to "PS" ?  If so, it's not necessary.  Windows explorer knows it's the same thing, so it leaves it unchanged.

Comment: Windows is case-insensitive by default. Have you tried renaming the file to something unique and then renaming it back to what you want it to be?

Comment: @Mokubai That worked. I'm not even sure why the programmer's guide mentions the casing of the name

Comment: @pensono that guide does say "if necessary"... did you find it to be necessary?

Comment: @Mokubai I haven't found it to be necessary. I was trying to change the name and I found it interesting that I couldn't.

Comment: Fair enough. Academic curiosity it is then. What about seeing if the file changes case when viewed in a command prompt or PowerShell? I'm not completely surprised at the behaviour you are seeing as it is what I've seen in the past, but to me it is not an important or difficult to work around "feature" as there are very few programs that actually work with files on Windows in a case-sensitive fashion.

Comment: You were trying to give a file the exact same name, but simply, change the case of the name.  Of course this isn't going to work on Windows.

Comment: @Mokubai Doesn't work either. I updated the question with the transcripts. Could it be related to the fact that the file is stored on a USB drive?

Comment: What is the filesystem type of the drive you're doing this on?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It's on FAT32

Comment: Yup, happens to me on Win 10 (but not Win 7)

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/q/391228

Comment: why on earth are you using `ls | grep 3000a.dll` just to get the file? Just use  `ls 3000a.dll` or even `ls 3*.dll`. Piping `ls` output to another command is also a bad idea (although it won't matter on Windows). See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32) is a [case-insensitive filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#File_capabilities). As such two files with the same name differing only in case isn't permitted. For example, you can't have two files named `PS3000a.dll` and `ps3000a.dll` in the same folder.

Therefore it seems that your attempt to rename the file `PS3000a.dll` to `ps3000a.dll` fails because Windows 10 knows *you're not really changing the filename*.  However, if you first rename the file to have a distinct name, *then* rename it a second time to use the case you intend, it works.

Curiously this isn't the case on Windows 7. Here's the file rename operation in Process Monitor. The operation is identical in all respects on Windows 10 and 7; the `ReplaceIfExists` flag is False and the Result is SUCCESS on both:

[image]

However, comparing the full traces only Windows 7 box follows the `SetRenameInformationFile` operation with a `WriteFile` operation:

**Windows 7**
[image]

**Windows 10**
[image]

Windows 10 simply doesn't write the updated information to the file system!

Comment: Windows 7 uses Windows Explorer while Windows 10 is File Explorer hence the difference in behavior

Comment: I don't see an explanation in that observation alone. The fact File Explorer came from Windows Explorer suggests it's plausible that any differences would be *intentional*.

Comment: Yes, it’s intentional, was pointing out a base explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When the new name differs from the old name only by capitalization then Windows Explorer will show the original capitalization.  If you quit the Explorer instance and relaunch it, go back to the folder, then you will see the new capitalization.

Comment: Closing and reopening explorer didn't work, although renaming it to "3000a.dll" and then to "PS3000a.dll" did

Comment: In my experience, I have had the exact same issue, renaming, then relaunching Explorer was all that was needed.

Comment: Maybe it makes a difference that the file in question is on a USB drive

Comment: Also, @pensono navigating to a different folder and then navigating back also works.  USB shouldn't make a difference though.

Comment: Navigating to a different folder and back doesn't show the correct name either :/

Comment: Well that stumps then.  It works for me.  Windows 10 Pro x64 here.